# Change Razer mouse dpi on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

I've recently change OS, from Windows to Linux Mint.
Everything went great so far, but the Razer Synapse software that handles all the settings of my mouse isn't compatible on Linux.
I quickly discovered OpenRazer, and luckly my mouse is in the supported device section. I tried to install it along with Polychromatic, but when I open it, it gives me an error, saying the mouse is detected, but not recognized.
I tried other solutions aswell, but with no success.
I want to just modify the DPI of my mouse, how can I do it in Linux Mint? Is there a way to store the DPI setting in the mouse itself?

Comment: Please provide logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than *OpenRazer* you can try with **razercfg** tool, predecessor of the former